# Docker Desktop 4.7.1 Kubernetes Stuck at starting (Already Re-Installed)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

So after updating to Docker Desktop 4.7.1, local kubernetes (v1.22.5) now is stuck at starting.

[image]

Uninstalled and re-installed latest Docker Desktop (4.7.1) but after restart, issue persists.

Running `kubectl get all -n kube-system`

Returns `Unable to connect to the server: EOF`

So clearly kubernetes isn't running.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

P.S. I am contemplating now on going back to Docker Desktop 4.6.x if I can't resolve this, but I do wish to be on latest Docker Desktop if possible.

I am on Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok after couple of hours of trouble shooting I was able to resolved the issue.

#### **Step 1: Reset Docker Desktop To Factory Defaults**

Right click docker icon on system tray, then choose **troubleshoot**, then click the **Reset to factory defaults** button.

[image]

#### **Step 2: Close Docker Desktop**

#### **Step 3: Delete the .kube folder**

It is located on `C:\Users\<user name>\.kube`

Make a backup for it if you want

#### **Step 4: Delete the pki folder**

It is located on `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Docker\pki`

Make a backup for it if you want

#### **Step 5: Add some entries in your hosts file**

```
192.168.1.5 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.5 gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1 docker-for-desktop
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
```

#### **Step 6: Run Docker Desktop As Administrator**

That's it, I was able to run local kubernetes cluster again

[image]

Comment: For me the fix was 
1. add follwoing entry in the host file, all other was still their but with different IP
127.0.0.1 docker-for-desktop
2. restart Docker Desktop
3. Restart Kubernetes Cluster

Answer (score 0):

Many of us enabled WSL2 integration and install Ubuntu from MS Store after installing Docker Desktop (at least >= 4.7.1) and starting Kubernetes, and found Kubernetes failed to start and stuck, for me the cause was due to the 'Ubuntu' in MS Store defaults to Distro 22.04.X which I believe is not working well with Docker Desktop and its Kubernetes engine.

The solution:

- run Windows Task Manager to end-task Docker Desktop
- uninstall 'Ubuntu' which is version 22.04.X in Windows installed
  apps
- run 'wsl -l -v' to look at existing status
- run 'wsl -t Ubuntu-22.04' to terminate Distro 'Ubuntu-22.04'
- run 'wsl --unregister Ubuntu-22.04' to unregister it
- from MS Store download and install Ubuntu-20.04
- run wsl and initialize Ubuntu-20.04
- run 'wsl -s Ubuntu-20.04' to set default to it
- in Docker Desktop Settings/Resources/WSL integration enable it and set it to default WSL distro 'Ubuntu-20.04'

Kubernetes will start fine and fast.

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled docker and re-installed it. Nothing else worked.